# How to enable (disable) PPTP multi login (of a same account) on Linux?

Tags: linux, vpn

I don't want let many users login to PPTP server of linux with single username and password.
is there any solution exists for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used pptpd myself, but its docs say that it just uses the underlying pppd.

pppd can be configured via pam, using `/etc/pam.d/ppp`.

One PAM module is `pam_listfile(8)` (at least available on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine), which can be configured to deny users with usernames listed in a specific file:

```
   Classic ´ftpusers´ authentication can be implemented with this entry in /etc/pam.d/ftpd:

       #
       # deny ftp-access to users listed in the /etc/ftpusers file
       #
       auth    required       pam_listfile.so \
               onerr=succeed item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers
```

You may be able to amend this for your site; by appending names to a file after a successful login and removing the names on logout, you could make it very difficult to have two connections created for the same user account.

Of course, this would be pretty brittle -- a dropped connection would need to have its line removed, and router reboots might annoy hundreds or thousands of users at once. I might suggest just truncating the whole file when users complain, and hope to avoid gross abuse of your system at best. (And the program to remove usernames would need to be carefully written to avoid races; you can use `lockfile(1)` or `dotlockfile(1)` to help you.)

Perhaps some periodic auditing would be another option: you could check the wutmp files (see `w(1)`, `lastlog(8)`) or process listings (`ps auxw` is nice) once in a while and see if people are abusing it, and handle it as a policy issue, rather than a software enforcement issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder why we can't do such thing in Linux! The solution you told is too complicated

Comment: It is a bit complicated, but I'm afraid that comes from combining multiple systems together. Is services theft really so large a deal for you that implementing a restriction is necessary? I still think occasional auditing would make more sense unless abuse is severe.

Answer (score 6):

PPTP multi login is enabled by default in Linux.
To disable multi login i just added next rows to /etc/ppp/ip-up

```
# disconnect new PPTP connection if user already connected
sleep 2
PID=$(cat /var/run/$PPP_IFACE.pid)
if [ $PID ]; then
    PROCCESS="$(last -w | grep ppp | grep still | grep $PPP_IFACE)"
    USERNAME=$(echo $PROCCESS | cut -d' ' -f1)
    NUMLOGINS="$(last -w | grep ppp | grep still | grep -c $USERNAME' ')"
    if [ $NUMLOGINS -gt 1 ]; then
        kill $PID
    fi
fi
```

This part just do disconnect any new connection if user is logged in.
Working fine for me on my Ubuntu 9.04

Comment: I had to use `$REALDEVICE` instead of `$PPP_IFACE` on CentOS 6 (pptpd 1.3.4).  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It works but only takes into consideration 8 characters from the username. If 2 users had the first 8 characters similar to one another it would kill the 2nd. The trick is nice though, it can be improved to get the exact full user name.

Comment: Change last with last -w and it would make it a whole lot easier to dodge this issue. Source: man last

Answer (score 0):

This works on Centos 7.6 for the time being.

```
#!/bin/bash
MAXLOGIN=2
# useful vars
#$DEVICE $IFNAME $PPPD_PID $MYPID $PEERNAME $_
#
LOGINS=`last -w $PEERNAME|grep ppp|grep still|wc -l`
if [ $LOGINS -gt $MAXLOGIN ]
    then
    echo `date` "too many logins of $LOGINS for $PEERNAME on $IFNAME pid $PPPD_PID" >>/tmp/mtg-pptp.log
    kill $PPPD_PID
    fi
```

Edit MAXLOGIN to meet your demands